# Unable to buy number from plivo using API

Tags: php, plivo

I am trying to buy or rent number from plivo using its api but in return i always get

{
"api_id": "424ce834-6498-11ec-aca5-0242ac110002",
"error": "not found"
}

i tried every thing but it did not work

here is the code
$ch = curl_init();

```
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/".$auth_id."/PhoneNumber/12513284788/");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $auth_id . ':' . $auth_token);

        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Ask the support of the vendor...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to use [subaccount credentials](https://console.plivo.com/subaccounts/) to purchase a number. You must use main account credentials, which are available on the Plivo dashboard. To assign a number to a subaccount, you can use the [Update a Number API](https://plivo.com/docs/numbers/api/account-phone-number#update-a-number) by specifying the respective subaccount Auth_ID as payload in the request.

If you have any questions or concerns, please reach out to our round-the-clock [support team](https://support.plivo.com/hc/en-us). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the error is not about PHP curl execution, ist a valid response from plivo server, maybe `$auth_id` didn't set properly or for example there is an error about the rest of the API URL.